# passing shell variable to plsql procedure

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql

I am trying to run my procedure from shell script. The issue is that parameters are not read by the procedure

```
#! /bin/bash

circle="GENX"
Date="2015/09/29"
version="V2"

/usr/ORACLE/u01/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus admin/admin@TESTDB <<"EOF"
begin
GEN_AUTOMATION.Delete_Invalid_Data('$circle','$Date','$version');
commit;
end;
/
"EOF"
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't like the heredoc limit string being quoted; I can reproduce and removing the quotes fixes it:

```
/usr/ORACLE/u01/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus admin/admin@TESTDB <<EOF
begin
GEN_AUTOMATION.Delete_Invalid_Data('$circle','$Date','$version');
commit;
end;
/
EOF
```

This is nothing to do with Oracle, it's how the shell and heredoc are working; this:

```
cat <<"EOF"
$circle
"EOF"
```

... prints `$circle` instead of `GENX` too.

[This is known behaviour](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

> Quoting or escaping the "limit string" at the head of a here document disables parameter substitution within its body. The reason for this is that quoting/escaping the limit string effectively escapes the $, `, and \ special characters, and causes them to be interpreted literally.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use unquoted `EOF` to have a parameter expansion. Due to [bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) for redirections:

> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only word (with no trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.
>
> The format of here-documents is:

```
<<[-]word
    here-document
  delimiter
```

> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or filename expansion is performed on word. If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

So, you have to make the word (`EOF` in your case) unquoted in the bash script, to make it work:

```
#! /bin/bash

circle="GENX"
Date="2015/09/29"
version="V2"

/usr/ORACLE/u01/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/bin/sqlplus admin/admin@TESTDB <<EOF
begin
GEN_AUTOMATION.Delete_Invalid_Data('$circle','$Date','$version');
commit;
end;
/
EOF
```